# Flex Button missing its skin inside itemRenderer class

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, itemrenderer, skin

I have tried to create an instance of Button class inside an itemRenderer element instance, but the button instance appears without its skin.
can someone explain me :

- Why does it happends ?
- How to fix it ?
- Am I doint it right or not ?

```
override protected function createChildren():void
{
    super.createChildren();

    btnControl           = new Button();
    btnControl.x         = 2;
    btnControl.y         = 22;
    btnControl.minHeight = 18;
    btnControl.minWidth  = 50;
    btnControl.height    = 18;
    btnControl.width     = Number( undefined );
    btnControl.label     = "контрол";
    btnControl.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onBtnControlClick );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from your code you're not adding the button to the displayList. Add

```
addElement(btnControl);
```

at the end if this is a Spark component you're extending; if it's an mx component use

```
addChild(btnControl);
```

Comment: i have done this, but actually the issue were with it's actuall width. thank you :)

Comment: My bad, seems like without setting it actuall width - the button remains without skin, just some shape alike.

So i did as follow : Inside 

override protected function measure() : void
{
    super.measure();
...
    btnControl.width = this.width;
}


It was something which i really didnt expected it. 
I hope it is usable solution for other peoples having similar problem.

Anyway if there is more or/and better solutions - they are more than wellcome :)

Comment: Again, this is all much easier to write in MXML. Is there any particular reason you want to write this in pure ActionScript?

Comment: By the way, that's not the way to use measure(). Measure() is for measuring the contents of your custom component, setting 'measuredWidth' and 'measuredHeight'. Later on in the component lifecycle these values will be used to size the component itself. If you want your button to span the entire component, you can use 'btnControl.percentWidth = 100' in the createChildren() method. No need to override measure().

Comment: I am still very new in Flex, thanks to you guys i understand alot of very uncommong up to this moment things, thanks again :)